# Is there any similar work environment for Python like the RStudio for R?

Tags: python, r, rstudio

Similarly, R language has the work environment in RStudio, so there I can run code and see plots, the output of the code run etc. What would be the equivalent for Python language? A program like RStudio where I could run code and see in that program the plot outputs, the console etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out JupyterLab or Jupyter?

Comment: Spyder is very similar

Answer (score 1):

Spyder IDE comes pretty close to the rstudio feel https://www.spyder-ide.org/.

But you'll  find that in the python community jupyter notebooks are more prevalent for data science work
https://jupyter.org/

Comment: So, to make things clear, a python script would be the same in spyder and in jupyter, the difference is just the work environment, isn't it?

Comment: @Miquel yes-----------------------

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not simply use RStudio to do your Programming in Python?
With the `Reticulate` package you can simply open and run Python Scripts in RStudio.

[image]

I don't know how efficient that is though.

For just Python I would advise Spyder IDE or Jupyter Notebook.